# wx.ListBox selection event

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython

I am using wx.Python to develop a GUI under MacOS.

the widget making me crazy is a simple ListBox. here's the instance

```
self.values = wx.ListBox(self, wx.ID_ANY, style = wx.LB_MULTIPLE|wx.LB_NEEDED_SB)
self.Bind(wx.EVT_LISTBOX, self.on_add_selection_values, self.values)
```

the problem is that when I perform a multiple line selection (with a single click while holding the shift button) it generates multiple time EVT_LISTBOX.

an idea of how to resolve this issue?

regards

Answer (score 1):

```
  Hover over first item
  Depress left mouse button
  Drag across all itemms
  Release mouse button
```

Is this how you are selecting the items?  ( You mention MAC, which seems to have its own queer ideas about how to use a mouse )

If so, I suggest:

```
Ignore the wxEVT_COMMAND_LISTBOX_SELECTED event.
Handle the mouse button up event wxEVT_LEFT_UP by calling GetSelections()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the mouse button up event will be launch at any time I click on the mouse. this is going to be a problem don't you think so ?

Comment: Why would it be a problem.  If there is no selection, then GetSelections() will return zero and your hasndler can quit.

Comment: This is because in the frame I have other widgets and the processing launched after the GetSelections() is kind of heavy so I don't want it to be launched unnecessarily.

Comment: I do not understand.  The event handler is launched when the user clicks on the ListBox.  If nothing is selected, it returns instantly.  Otherwise, it is neccessary!

Comment: Indeed this is why it is driving me crazy! Maybe I am dealing with a macOs peculiarity. I expect that it will launches an event maybe when I select the first item and when I drag across the Items and release the button.

Comment: To make that happen, you need to handle the button release event, wxEVT_LEFT_UP, as I describe in the answer.